# How to get complete page source in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used :

```
var generatedSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML; ,
```

but I'm getting partial content only, page has around 600 lines and I'm just getting around 250 lines.

Comment: How are you counting the lines?

Comment: The second approach looks good. Have you tried to compare your actual source and your 250-lines-result? What is the difference? Which lines are missing?

Comment: almost 50% it showing

Comment: above code worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need before to load the whole page and only after you can get the whole page:

```js
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  var htmlInPage = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, which is working in all modern browsers.

Here is an example, which shows that it outputs all the text, scripts, styles etc.

```js
console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

```css
body {
  color: darkgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
Check your console
```